Time-reversal and phase space density; Is it symmetric?
In "statistical physics of particles" of M.Kardar, p.60, there is a statement as consequences of Liouville theorem:


Under the action of time reversal, $(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}, t) \rightarrow(-\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q},-t)$, the Poisson bracket $\{\rho, \mathcal{H}\}$ changes sign, and Eq. (3.9) implies that the density reverses its evolution, that is, $\rho(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}, t)=\rho(-\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q},-t)$.


Here, $(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q})$ is momentum and position each, and $\rho$ is phase space density of Gibbs ensemble. $\mathcal{H}$ is Hamiltonian of system. Eq.(3.9) is
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\left\{\rho, \mathcal{H}\right\}
$$
I wonder how $\rho(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}, t)=\rho(-\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q},-t)$ is derived as stated. It seems additional information is needed, like $\rho(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q}, 0)$.
